# How to put a Kendo ListView into the content of a Kendo PanelBar?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview, kendo-panelbar

I have to put a **dynamically** filled ListView into a **dynamically created** Panel.
The listview is in a div with the id `listView`

I tried the following:

index.js:

```
panelbar.append({   
            text: "Group1",
            encoded: false,
            content: $("\#listView")          //puts [object Object]
            //OR
            content: '<object type="text/html" data="#listView" ></object>' //puts the whole html-page into panel, very interesting behaviour
 })
```

> Is it possible to put a div into a panel or do I have to use partial
>   views/  a long string where the listview is built and **how**.

---

I also tried to put the ListView as template of the PanelBar:

index.html:

```
<script id="panelbar-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
    <script>
        $("\#listView").kendoListView()
    </script>
</script>

<div id="panelBar" style="margin:0 auto; width: 90%">
     @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
        .Name("Panelbar")
        .TemplateId("panelbar-template")
        ..
```

Comment: [Here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/partialview-in-kendo-panelbar) is one way.

Comment: thanks a lot, this helps for my first group (for others: see my answer to this question). But I still need to change the content dynamically (in javascript)

Comment: Might need more details, but there is an option to return the content dynamically via AJAX: `.LoadContentFrom(Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { id = detail.Id }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one panel, I put my ListView into a 'MyPartialView.cshtml'
 and wrote the following in my 'index.cshtml':

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
    .Name("panelbar")
    .ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Multiple)
    .Items(panelbar =>
    {
    panelbar.Add().Text("Group1")
         .Expanded(true)
         .Content(@<text> <div> abc @Html.Partial("MyPartialView")</div></text>); //THIS DID IT
    //;
    })
)
```

**for dynamic contents, I worked with Partial Views**